# Python Multiprocessing.Process class in windows produces AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'testClass1' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am working on a multiprocessing module in python. I have a code similar to below which works perfectly in Ubuntu but not in Windows. As i want to run it on windows server, I have to make it work on windows.

```
# Importing libraries
from multiprocessing import Process

def testFunc(value=0):
    print("I am in test function", value)

class testClass1(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super(testClass1, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        testFunc(1)
        print("Done ran testFunc and back to testClass1")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = testClass1()
    t1.start()
```

Below is the error/warning message i am getting on windows platform

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "c:\users\user1\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
>       exitcode = _main(fd)
>     File "c:\users\user1\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 115, in _main
>       self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
>   AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'testClass1' on

Let me know how to resolve this error in windows.

I tried searching for similar issues on web but could not find solution which resolves this.

Also, If you think this question is duplicate point me to the original question and let me get this resolved before closing the question.

Comment: Does your example reproduce the error for you on Windows? It doesn't for me on Ubuntu when I switch start-method to "spawn" (default on Windows). Class definition has to be at the top level (like in your example). Try with adding `t1.join()` below `t1.start()`.

Comment: Hi @Darkonaut, I have access to two windows azure servers and my windows laptop and all of them reproduces same error. Error occurs at {t1.start()}